# Animating a path between two objects on HTML5 canvas

Tags: html, canvas, impactjs

We're developing a game with impactjs that allows 'chaining' of entities as they are clicked.  Basically this just draws a line between the two points, with a neon glow effect.  So far, so good.  Now, we have a request to make the 'chain' connections animated - fire, sparkles, etc.  Essentially things that seem like they'd need actual graphic animations to look right.  As the entities can be any distance/angle from each other, we're stuck at how to best implement a solution for this - that is, how to draw a diagonal image, for example, between two random points that we can animate.  Any thoughts our suggestions on how to pull this off would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe create a particle entity with an Animation Sheet containing the necessary animations/particle effects. And then draw these particles along the line that from point A to point B.

When you want to animate it to fire/sparkles etc. run the animation for all those entities. in that line.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be inclined to agree with Prat. Particle effects would most likely be what you need. 
Here is a tutorial on generating particle effects in impact.js that might help you out.

http://www.pointofimpactjs.com/snippets/view/24/particle-effects-generation